# convert hexadecimal number to decimal whith shell script

Tags: shell, sh

I need to convert a number from hexadecimal form to decimal form using shell script

for example :

```
convert()
{
    ...
    echo x=$decimal
}
```

result :

```
convert "0x148FA1"
x=1347489
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can convert in many different ways, all within bash, and relatively easy.

To convert a number from hexadecimal to decimal:

```
$ echo $((0x15a))
346

$ printf '%d\n' 0x15a
346

$ perl -e 'printf ("%d\n", 0x15a)'
346

$ echo 'ibase=16;obase=A;15A' | bc
346
```

Answer (score 6):

You can check this [link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-convert-hex-to-decimal-number/). Fundamentally below code will help you.

```
h2d(){
  echo "ibase=16; $@"|bc
}
d2h(){
  echo "obase=16; $@"|bc
}
```

It is in pure shell scripting solution.

Comment: An elegant solution that doesn't rely on bash. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a python interpreter available, you can always do:

```
#!/bin/sh
x="0x23"
val=`python -c "print int('$x', 16)"`
echo $val
```